# How do I get a bridge network to work for VirtualBox with Linux guest on a Mac OS X host

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox, virtualization, bridge

Does anybody have the step by step configuration process that would allow VirtualBox running a Linux/Ubuntu guest on a Mac OS X host use the bridge type network using Ethernet and wireless? I have read that it does work and it doesn't work, trying to find a definite answer. I want the guest environment to look like a separate box.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a bridge network working on OSX with a Ubuntu guest VM. You need a network connection for this to work. I have my nic configured via DHCP in OSX and then I statically assigned the guest `eth0` an IP on the same subnet.

With this set up I could SSH to my Ubuntu guest; with entries in `/etc/hosts` on OSX I was able to access internal domains I'd set up in apache on the Ubuntu guest.

I simply installed Ubuntu, in the VM settings, set the adapter to a bridge connection. Boot Ubuntu and be sure to configure `/etc/network/interfaces`

Mine looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

OSX would pick up an IP address on the same subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.102), I could see the guest from the host just fine.

```
ssh 192.168.0.20
```

Hope this helps.

I'm struggling to get host-only networking set up so I can communicate with the guest VM without an active internet connection.